# Analytic function on $D$ such that $| f ( z ) | = | \sin z | , \forall z \in$ $D ,$ then prove that $f(z)=c\sin z$ for some constant c

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $D$ be a domain and let $f ( z )$ be an analytic
function on $D$ such that $| f ( z ) | = | \sin z | , \forall z \in$
$D ,$ then prove that $f(z)=c\sin z$ for some constant c.

Can we consider the quotient $\frac{f(z)}{\sin z}$? But I am not getting how the quotient has removable singularity at zeros of $\sin z$

Comment: All the zeros of $\sin$ are simple.

Comment: Ya correct, but how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** If $\sin(a)=0$ for some $a \in D$ deduce that $f(a)=0$ in $D$ and hence there exists an alaytic function $h(z)$ such that $f(z)=(z-a)h(z)$.

Use this to show that $\frac{f(z)}{\sin(z)}$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$.

Comment: What you mean by deduce that $f(a)=0$?

Comment: @RIYASUDHEENT.K If $\sin(a)=0$, then $\lvert\sin(a)\rvert=0$, so $|f(a)|=0$. Hence $f(a)=0$.